# Replace all values in IQueryable with string based on results using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have an IQueryable I selected from a database that contains a field called "NewValue". This field will either contain a 0, 1, or 2. I want to replace the value with a string based of which number it is.
i.e 0 = "Active". I know IQueryables aren't used to change values mostly just for querying but I need to use it in the next line to add to the ViewModel

```
var AssessmentList = assessment                    
.Select(p => new LogManagementViewModel
{
   newValue = p.NewValue,
});
```

How can I change all the values in assement.NewValue to a string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var values = new [] {"StrValue1", "StrValue2", "StrValue"};

var AssessmentList = assessment                    
    .AsEnumerable()
    .Select(p => new LogManagementViewModel
        {
            newValue = values[p.NewValue],
        });
```

Comment: I tried this before and it gave me an error message saying that a LINQ IQueryable cannot contain an array index. I'm paraphrasing I forgot the actual error code

Comment: @Loogawa - that's what you should start from. In this case add `AsEnumerable()` call : var AssessmentList = assessment.AsEnumerable().Select(...);` or use some other approach to make it working with SQL

Comment: That worked great. Although there were a lot of good answers on here I could have done too. The only thing I was missing from my first attempt doing this was the .AsEnumerable(). I still don't really understand how this works though.

Comment: @Loogawa, the thing is that you have initially an `IQueryable` interface which Linq-to-Sql or Linq-to-Entities tries to transform into corresponding query. It will work fine if you have simple constructions in query (comparison for example) which can be transformed into SQL. But this `values` array cannot be transformed into SQL code and that's why you've seen that error. Adding `AsEnumerable` returns `IEnumerable` interface and because of that your following statements will be executed via `Linq-to-objects` which works fine with arrays.

Comment: okay that makes sense. You have helped me to understand LINQ a lot better thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
var dictionary = new Dictionary<int, string>
{
    { 0, "Active" },
    { 1, "Inactive" },
    // etc
};

var AssessmentList = assessment                    
.Select(p => new LogManagementViewModel
{
    newValue = dictionary[p.NewValue],
});
```

This would work for mapping between other types as well.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest and cleanest would be with a mapping method:

```
string MapToString(int value)
{
    //..
}

var AssessmentList = assessment                    
.Select(p => new LogManagementViewModel
{
   NewValue = MapToString(p.NewValue),
});
```

Answer (score 0):

One way:

Add a new computed property onto your class (assuming you have a partial class outside of any generated code). Then that computed class can do the translation however it needs to. Your view model can reference this computed value.

Answer (score 0):

I would make a constructor overload in your LogManagementViewModel that does that work for you, something like this:

```
public LogManagementViewModel(int NewValue)
{
  switch(NewValue)
  {
      case 0:
         this.NewValue = "Active";
         break;
       // etc...
  }
}
```

IMO, this places the logic in it's proper place, let the your view model translate it as it should be, it's not the responsibility of your LINQ/Database queries.

Comment: The problem is I have other things that use the viewModel where it won't be a number, but I think I can test this with extra logic. This is a great idea though. Thanks

Comment: You can always have multiple constructors, make a constructor that fits each of your requirements.

Comment: I really liked this answer but @snowbear was very close to what I had already done. Just had to add .AsEnumerable() so I will give it to him. But I do like this answer